# AmCharts, capturing click event for period selector

Tags: javascript, amcharts

I'm using AmCharts 3 and I was wondering is there a way to capture an event for clicking the buttons of the period selector?

[The Docs](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptstockchart/PeriodSelector) state I can add a listener to the period selector of the type 'changed' but then the event runs almost anytime

There is a listener for 'zoomed', but it runs every time I zoom my chart regardless if I clicked the period selector

Here's my attempt:

```
chart = AmCharts.makeChart(scope.vm.chartId, chartSettings);
    AmCharts.addInitHandler(function () {
    // add events to item
    _.each(chart.panels, function (item) {
    //item.addListener("zoomed", onZoomed);
    item.addListener("changed", function(e) {
    console.debug("changed " + e.periodString);
   });
 });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are initiating through a configuration object, I suggest you use the new 'listeners' property supported in the latest version of AmCharts to add an event handler to the periodSelector object on your chartSettings object. It should work.

Answer (score 4):

You can use period selector's [`changed`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptstockchart/PeriodSelector#changed) event for that.

I.e.:

```
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart( "chartdiv", {
  "type": "stock",

  // ...

  "periodSelector": {
    "position": "left",
    "periods": [ {
      "period": "MM",
      "selected": true,
      "count": 1,
      "label": "1 month"
    }, {
      "period": "YYYY",
      "count": 1,
      "label": "1 year"
    }, {
      "period": "YTD",
      "label": "YTD"
    }, {
      "period": "MAX",
      "label": "MAX"
    } ],
    "listeners": [ {
      "event": "changed",
      "method": function( event ) {
        if ( event.predefinedPeriod !== undefined ) {
          console.log( event.predefinedPeriod, event.count );
        }
      }
    } ]
  },

  // ...
} );
```

Please note that this event will be executed when changing dates using date input fields as well, hence the check if `event.predefinedPeriod` is defined.

Please also keep in mind that default period is selected on chart init as well. So this event will be triggered when the chart is first loaded without any user interaction.

Here's a [working demo](http://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/e7999486317951c950bd3867f80b7e78).

Comment: the plunk also returns undefineds in console when I click the buttons, but other then that it looks great. i'll test it tomorrow. thanks!

Comment: @svarog, I suggest you mark this answer as the correct one rather than mine. Other than being more detailed, martynasma is one of the developers of AmCharts, if I'm not mistaken, and therefore probably knows what he's talking about.