# Send ajax request in PeriodSelector AMChart

Tags: grails, grails-2.0, amcharts

I have this javascript code to draw an amchart stock, just the PeriodSelector part:

```
 var periodSelectorAjax = new AmCharts.PeriodSelector();
 periodSelectorAjax.periods = [
    {period: "F1", label: "Phase 1"},
    {period: "F2", label: "Phase 2"},
    {period: "F3", label: "Phase 3"},
    {period: "MAX", selected: true, label: "MAX"}
];
```

I need to intercept when user click on period to reload the graph, I see that I can do it with this, from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33065926/amcharts-capturing-click-event-for-period-selector):

```
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart( "chartdiv", {
"type": "stock",

 // ...

"periodSelector": {
"position": "left",
"periods": [ {
  "period": "MM",
  "selected": true,
  "count": 1,
  "label": "1 month"
}, {
  "period": "YYYY",
  "count": 1,
  "label": "1 year"
}, {
  "period": "YTD",
  "label": "YTD"
}, {
  "period": "MAX",
  "label": "MAX"
} ],
"listeners": [ {
  "event": "changed",
  "method": function( event ) {
    if ( event.predefinedPeriod !== undefined ) {
      console.log( event.predefinedPeriod, event.count );
    }
  }
} ]
},

// ...
} );
```

But I don't know how to put the last listeners part and use it with my code.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either use the [`addListener`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptstockchart/PeriodSelector#addListener) method or just set the [`listeners`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptstockchart/PeriodSelector#listeners) array directly on your periodSelectorAjax variable.

`addListener` example:

```
periodSelectorAjax.addListener("changed", function(event) {
  // your code here
});
```

`listeners` property example:

```
periodSelectorAjax.listeners = [{
  "event": "changed",
  "method": function(event) {
    // ...
  }
}]
```